# variable += 1 in python function adding incorrectly by 2

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-3.8

I have this function `move()` function in a class which is incorrectly adding 2 instead of 1 in a line containing `self.coords[1] += 1`

here's the file:

```
class Actor():
    def __init__(self, start, limits, barriers):
        self.coords = start
        self.limits = limits
        self.barriers = barriers
    
    def canmove(self, direction):
        moving = self.coords
        if(direction == 'up'):
            moving[1] -= 1
        elif(direction == 'right'):
            moving[0] += 1
        elif(direction == 'down'):
            moving[1] += 1
        elif(direction == 'left'):
            moving[0] -= 1
        
        if((moving[0] > self.limits[0]) or (moving[1] > self.limits[1]) or (-1 in moving) or (moving in self.barriers)):
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def move(self, direction):
        if(direction == 'up'):
            if self.canmove('up'):
                self.coords[1] -= 1
        elif(direction == 'right'):
            if self.canmove('right'):
                self.coords[0] += 1
        elif(direction == 'down'):
            if self.canmove('down'):
                self.coords[1] += 1
        elif(direction == 'left'):
            if self.canmove('left'):
                self.coords[0] -= 1
```

I know the `canmove()` function doesn't quite work yet but it doesn't interfere with the results.

*When running `Actor.move('up')` it is decreasing `Actor.coords[1]` by two instead of one*.

Here's what happens (even when ignoring the `canmove()` check):

```
>>> from actor import Actor
>>> actor = Actor([2, 2], [10, 5], [[4, 4]])
>>> actor.move('down')  
>>> actor.coords
[2, 4]
```

and `actor.move(down)` is supposed to increase the value of `actor.coords[1]` by one, not two.

Comment: [github of this project](https://github.com/ItzJaum/coords-py/) containing more context

Comment: The code you posted in your question differs than the code posted in Github. Which is the correct one?

Comment: There is no line containing `self.coords[1] += 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a weird little nuance where in your `canmove` function [`moving = self.coords`](https://github.com/ItzJaum/coords-py/blob/main/actor.py#L8) does not actually copy the list, it just copies a reference to where the list is located in memory ([here is an explanation for what is going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent#answer-47258728)). So both `moving` and `self.coords` point to the same list, and this is causing your `canmove` function to move your character (and then when the `move` function moves the character it gets moved twice). What you want to do is:

```
import copy
moving = copy.deepcopy(self.coords)
```

And that will copy the list and all items inside of the list.

---

Comment: `canmove()` checks and modifies `moving`, not `self.coords`, or does that somehow link up?

Comment: @JoãoH.L.Corrêa As is already stated in the above answer; `moving = self.coords` doesn't make a copy of `self.coords`, it's a pointer to the same list. That means that when you make a change to `moving`, it's changing the same list that is in the `self.coords` variable.